# create my own jquery form from sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

How can I create my own custom jQuery form from within SharePoint Designer 2010, with my own validation tactics for the form, and my own post data processing with Ajax?  Any good tuturials out there?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it. It's not the most elegant, but doable. Through SharePoint Designer, create your custom HTML form on an .HTML page. If it involves javaScript or a posting data to another URL, place the appropriate code on the same page. Save it. Then on your publishing .aspx page which will have a web part, load a Page Viewer to call the custom HTML form you just created. If you need additional JavaScript to modify the form after the DOM is ready, jQuery is excellent for the job.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer, as it may help other users with the same problem. Thank you!